# How to format a reference to a video game in llncs - documentclass?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, lncs

How would a reference to a video game look if lncs would support it (it does not). My professor just waived it with "add the relevant information in a note!"

So right now it looks like this in my .bib file:

```
@software{game:rogue,
    author = {Michael C. Toy and Kenneth C. R. C. Arnold and Glenn Wichman},
    title = {{Rogue}},
    year = {1980},
    note = {[Video Game for PC]}
}
```

that creates:

Toy, M.C., Arnold, K.C.R.C., Wichman, G.: Rogue (1980) [Video Game for PC].

That just looks horrible ...

Also I found other sources that recommend to format a video game reference as:

TITLE. AUTHOR/DEVELOPER, OPERATING SYSTEM/CONSOLE, STUDIO YEAR

but every kind of bibstyle does it different. How would lncs do this? Can I edit some file so the "correct" way is actually added to how the lncs documentclass/bibstyle does it? (`splncs`)

Also how would I reference a self-published video game that got released on multiple systems at release, like most indie games are today? Who is the author of a video game if there is mostly a studio referenced for the creation of it? Do movie references give a better example? (They are not supported by lncs too ...)